# How to delete multiple lines after a match in ansible?

Tags: python, ansible, pattern-matching, devops

Is there a way in ansible to delete multiple lines after a pattern matched?

For example, I have a file with following contents, and need to delete lines 'bbbbbb', 'cccccc'. However I really do not know what are those two lines as they are generated dynamically. I only know line 'aaaa:'

```
start contents
aaaa:
    bbbbbb
    cccccc
other contents
```

Comment: use blockinfile but you will have to add two marker begin and end after line aaaa: . Then only, ansible can delete these two lines without taking care of content between those two lines.

Comment: @SAURABHPANDEY : could you post the lines

Comment: @VladimirBotka : could you refresh the page, Thanks